# How to copy a text from one file into another file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

How can I copy the line of a text file (**C:\dos\crusoe\src.txt**) if the text `meghana` is in  it, and paste the line into another file (**C:\dos\crusoe\trgt.txt**)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe on Windows you'd be looking for `findstr` - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

For example:

```
findstr /x /c:<string> <source-file-name> > <target-file-name>
```

Comment: Remember that > erases the target file while >> appends to it.

Answer (score 0):

An example using `find`:

```
(type "sourcefile" | find "Meghana" 2>nul) >"targetpath"
```

Comment: How is this better than using ```findstr```,  which was suggested almost eleven years ago?

Comment: @Scott It may not be better, just showing an example